# How to best support multiple hardware keys (yubikeys, etc.) as a web app?

Tags: multi-factor, yubikey, u2f, fido

I've implemented second factor authentication for my web app via FIDO U2F, and am testing using a Yubikey.

I have read that it is best practice to associate multiple hardware keys in case one is lost, but I wanted to know what the security implications were, as documentation is fairly sparse.

When an authentication attempt is made, I query the server for the challenge. The challenge is constructed using the key handle I've saved during registration, but how would I know what key the user is going to use, since the request for the challenge doesn't contain any identifying information about which key is used?

I can send back multiple challenges based on the key handles I have for that user, but even then, in the browser, I can only attempt signing of one key at a time, unless I am missing something?

Also, silly question, but during key registration, I received a `keyHandle` and `publicKey` back. Is one of them okay to share, or are both supposed to be kept private (the `publicKey` name infers that it is okay to share)?

Comment: Most sites that allow me to use multiple second factors let me have a default one, and a link to switch to a different one...  I.e., Google asks for my U2F dongle, but I can switch to burning one of my one-time-use tokens.—If you want to let users have multiple U2F dongles, you can let them name it, and they can pick which to use.

Comment: Keep in mind that "What I've seen" isn't the same as "This is advice that infosec professionals give."  I left the comment in hopes that it'll be helpful, but it isn't something that I've looked into enough to be confident to write a full answer about it.